# How do I get object based on key value and then get the sibling key names and values

Tags: javascript, object

I want an object and the structure which looks for instance like:

```js
{ "videos": [
    {
      "id": 501437,
      "artist": "Pants Velour",
      "title": "All In",
      "release_year": 2014,
      "genre_id": 14
    },
    {
      "id": 501649,
      "artist": "El Koala",
      "title": "Veni paca to",
      "release_year": 2014,
      "genre_id": 8
    },
  {
    id: 560599,
    artist: 'Jay Sean',
    title: 'Sex 101',
    release_year: 2012,
    genre_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 560983,
    artist: 'The Cranberries',
    title: 'Zombie',
    release_year: 1994,
    genre_id: 8
  }]
  }
```

And req.params.id is for example **560599**. How do I get the entire object based on the id? So in the end I want all the key names + values nested with the matching Id number.Check below how I want the object.

```js
  {
    id: 560599,
    artist: 'Jay Sean',
    title: 'Sex 101',
    release_year: 2012,
    genre_id: 1
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const id = 560599;

const tempObj = temp.videos.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue.id === id) {
    accumulator = currentValue;
  }

  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let selected = videos.find(v => v.id == req.params.id);
```

To find an element within array that matches your criteria.